# Can't Read (!@#$...and Capital Letters) from console with ReadConsoleInput

Tags: c, windows, console

have wrote this app which reads input from console.

```
for(; ; )
{


   GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(stdinInput, &numEvents);

   if (numEvents != 0) {

       INPUT_RECORD eventBuffer;

      ReadConsoleInput(stdinInput, &eventBuffer, 1, &numEventsRead);


        if (eventBuffer.EventType == KEY_EVENT) {

            if(eventBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
            {

                printf("%c",eventBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar);
                dataBuffer[bufferLen++] = eventBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar;
                dataBuffer[bufferLen]  = '\0';            

                if ( dataBuffer[bufferLen] == 99 || eventBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar == '\r' ) {
                printf("User Wrote: %s\n",dataBuffer);

                memset(dataBuffer,0,sizeof(dataBuffer));
                bufferLen = 0;
                }



            }
        }

    }
}
```

It puts the data on a buffer and then it prints out the buffer. The problem occurs when im using `Shift` or `CapsLock` to write Capital letters or `! @ # $ %` characters. Then it prints out NOTHING.

Ive tried something with the `VK_LSHIFT` code but didn't worked.

Also if try to write something in other language than English  it prints out something like this `▒├╞▒├╞▒├│▒├│` It cannot recognize the other language.

Can someone give me a hint on how to fix those problems ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReadConsoleInput returns events for each keystroke.  For example, if you type `SHIFT+A` to get a capital A then you'll receive four key events:  `SHIFT` down, `A` down, `A` up, `SHIFT` up.

The `SHIFT` key does not have a corresponding ASCII code so `eventBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar` is set to zero.  This zero terminates the string you are building in `dataBuffer` so you don't see anything typed after the `SHIFT` key.

The simplest fix is to ignore any key event with an ASCII code of zero.

Additionally, if you want this to work well with foreign languages you might do better to use ReadConsoleInputW and `eventBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.UnicodeChar`.  Better yet, compile it all as a Unicode app.

Comment: Thanks a lot arx. That worked except from `ReadConsoleInputW` that needed to be `ReadConsoleInputA`. Thanks once again!

Comment: @F.N ReadConsoleInputW works but you need to change everything to use Unicode: change `dataBuffer` to contain `wchar_t`, change `printf` to `wprintf`, etc.